# Referring to @Autowired component in another component's constructor

Tags: java, spring, junit, autowired

Can a Spring component's constructor refer to an @Autowired component, or does the autowiring happen too late?

I have an example that's something like this:

```
@Component
public class A {
    public A() { ... }
    ...
}

@Component
public class B {
    @Autowired A a;
    public B() {
        some code using a.getThisOrThat() ... // fails, a is null
    }
}
```

and in the config file:

```
<bean id="a" class="some.packagename.A" />
<bean id="b" class="some.packagename.B" depends-on="a" />
```

I've confirmed using `System.out.println` that A's constructor is called before B's; however, inside B's constructor, `a` is null.  I'm running this as a JUnit unit test, using `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`.  If I defer the initialization in `B` until the first time another method is called, it works fine--`a` has been set up.

Is this the expected behavior?

Is it possible that the behavior is different when `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` is being used?

Is there a way to get this to work (aside from deferring the initialization in `B`)?

Comment: How could `a` ever be non-null **inside** the constructor body?

Comment: Your options are constructor injection and `@PostConstruct` initialization methods.

Comment: `@DependsOn`/`depends-on` only sets an ordering for bean initialization, nothing else.

Comment: OK, I see--Spring can't touch the object until it's been created which means the constructor has to have been completed... I missed that.  Anyway, thanks for pointing me to the alternatives.